# Serilog Azure EventHub Sink output template json

Tags: json, azure-eventhub, serilog

So, I am battling and trying to figure this out.
I have Serilog and using EventHub to log errors. 
It took a while to find but I needed it to be serialized into JSON so I used this:

```
logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.Sink(new AzureEventHubSink(eventHubClient, new JsonFormatter()))
                .CreateLogger();
```

Great. Now, when I write the exception:

```
logger.Error(ex, "An Error Occurred");
```

It writes it BUT the exception is written in 1 field (big long strong).

Is there a way to tell SeriLog to write each property of the exception in its own field (think of it as a SQL table with fields)?

How about changing the outputTemplate but still using JsonFormatter, as there is no overload to accept the output template?

I am using Stream Analytics to do some querying and it makes it better (MUCH better) to have each exception property as its own field column rather than just 1 field with the entire JSON string in there, and I need to do cross joins on another data source.

Thank you.

Comment: Where do you want those columns? In essence, Event Hub message is just a byte array with some metadata. It's up to the client to interpret it properly.

Comment: I understand but SA essentially takes the data from EH and just spits out the columns/props found in it and displays it. So when I do a SELECT * FROM - it shows me the columns from SeriLog like Timestamp, Level, MessageTemplate etc... but along with that, I want to add each exception property to the list of columns next to say "MessageTemplate" or even at least "ClassName" as its own rightful column. You can modify the outputTemplate format but cannot seem to do that with the JSON formatter overload. SeriLog just serializes the exception into its own field - I don't want that. Want EACH field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the only way is to inherit from JsonFormatter and then override the WriteException method and write the Property in question....

```
    WriteJsonProperty("ClassName", exception.GetType(), ref delim, output);
    WriteJsonProperty("Message", exception.Message, ref delim, output);
```